# Properly implementing a Jenkins Authentication Plugin

Tags: authentication, spring-security, jenkins-plugins

I've written a Jenkins plugin that implements a SecurityRealm that specifies a custom Security Filter.
That filter takes the username and password and authenticates it by posting it to a 3rd party system. There is an interim MFA stage that requires me to use jenkins login page customisation to show the user an MFA prompt.

Finally after after authorisation I do this (with the Authentication Object) :

```
//recreate session (fixation)
SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(a);
//redirect to /jenkins/
```

Every subsequent request goes through my filter, and I can see that my Authorisation object is still on the session.
Very few of the requests made are authorised against my user, most of them (API calls) are attempting to authorise against the 'anonymous' SID.

Does anyone have any even the most vague idea of what the problem is?